# Who is good at scraping websites? I have a tough one

Tags: web-scraping, maps, gis

I'm a very amateur data analyst. I'm trying to get the information off of a GIS map on this website:

http://www.gimsys.net/irep/SIG/th_Reseau/default.asp

I'd like to get the raw data for the layers on the map, but it seems like the website can't be scraped because it just loads images.

Any tips?

Much appreciated!

- Laurent

Comment: I think you're stuck unless you can figure out how to persuade the server to return anything other than an image. But there's no obvious query parameters to try, and no clues in the source code. Try the TZ GIS user group: http://www.tzgisug.org/wp/ who might know where to get shapefiles of that data. Or maybe its on OpenStreetMap - but some countries are wary of publishing power infrastructure data...

Comment: Thank you Spacedman! I'll see if I can find the info on those forums. Otherwise I'll have to take the long way of screenshots+georeferencing+digitizing.